# Commerce B2C store creation throws "An unexpected error occurred."

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2c, e-commerce

I have a developer account and trying to create a SF store using B2C templates provided by SF, however, I'm encountering an error every time I press create.

Error: **An unexpected error occurred. Try again or contact your Salesforce administrator for help.**

What could be the reasons for this error. Since I'm a beginner I can't make sense of this error nor the reasons behind it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In context, if it's the same error I have, this is with regards Salesforce Commerce Cloud. One of the templates when creating the store is called B2C Commerce but every time it's selected, it generates the error below. I'm guessing something must be configured incorrectly somewhere preventing the template from being created but I have yet to determine what so if anyone has any ideas, their input would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Had the exact same issue. Did you find which is the configuration problem?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
To solve this issue we need to compile all apex classes:

1. Goto Setup >> Custom Code >> Apex Classes. Click the link "Compile all classes"
2. It will take minutes. Then you will see “Compilation COmplete Compilation Succesful”

Note)

For more information about Apex Class compile, please check Salesforce document Manage Apex Classes

Answer (score 0):

We need to Enable Commerce  Go to Setup=> Commerce=> under Settings

Enable 'Commerce'.

(you will able to access B2C Template after this step)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign B2B Commerce Permission Set License under Permission Set License Assignments to your admin user first to be able to Enable Commerce under Settings and then retry.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite before using B2C templates.

1. In Setup, assign "Commerce Admin" Permission Set to your user.
2. Setup-> Enable "Commerce" toggle.

It should work.